# How to make refresh table in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I want to know about code that will auto refresh a table in HTML using Google Apps Script.

I've already tried `refresh()`, but it doesn't work or maybe the problem is me don't know what exactly `refresh()` is.

---

JavaScript Code:

```
document.getElementById('kolom_pencarian').addEventListener('input',cari);

function cari()
{
  var keyword = document.getElementById("kolom_pencarian").value;      
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(hasilPencarian).SearchEngine(keyword);
  var tbody = document.getElementById("table-body");
  tbody.refresh();

}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(hasilPencarian).getDataTabel();

});

function hasilPencarian(data)
{
      var tbody = document.getElementById("table-body");
      data.forEach(function(r)
      {    
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        var col1 = document.createElement("td");
        col1.textContent=r[0];
        var col2 = document.createElement("td");
        col2.textContent=r[1];
        var col3 = document.createElement("td");
        col3.textContent=r[2];
        var col4 = document.createElement("td");
        col4.textContent=r[3];
        var col5 = document.createElement("td");
        col5.textContent=r[4];
        var col6 = document.createElement("td");
        col6.textContent=r[5];
        var col7 = document.createElement("td");
        col7.textContent=r[6];
        row.appendChild(col1);
        row.appendChild(col2);
        row.appendChild(col3);
        row.appendChild(col4);
        row.appendChild(col5);
        row.appendChild(col6);
        row.appendChild(col7);
        tbody.appendChild(row);
      });
```

Comment: You need to `getDataTabel()` again and run `hasilPencarian`

Comment: thanks, that help me out, i tried your suggestion and i get the value what i want. but the new problem is, that will make new table and the old table stay on my page. i want the old table get replace with new table and so on when i type new keyword.

Comment: Clear the table first in `hasilPencarian`. Something like `tbody.innerHtml=""`

Comment: Umm, BTW how to close this post? or i just need to delete this post?

Comment: You can add it as a answer and accept the answer, if you think that'll be helpful to others in the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TheMaster has solved my problem, I just need to use innerHtml in my code.